# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: e. Path '', line 0, position 0 while trying to delete documents in documentDB

Tags: c#, string, azure-cosmosdb

I have a string as an ID for documentDB which is pretty long.

```
var longId = "Ardell Natural Lashes are popular lashes because women love that they're lightweight, reusable, easy-to-apply and give the desired, natural look of full, beautiful lashes. \n• Ardell false eyelashes are made from sterilized, 100% human hair."
var documentlink = database + "/doc/" + longId;
```

When I want to delete the document I need the document link which is created from ID. When I execute that function, I got this exception message

```
"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: e. Path '', line 0, position 0 while trying to delete documents in documentDB."
```

Can anyone suggest me how to change that string to be a usable one in documentDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues here:

1. In order to use '\n' in a string, you need to escape it like '\n', in order for JSON to serialize it properly. Once you do that you will get a meaningful message from DocumentDB: "The resource name presented contains invalid character '\'". 
   We don't allow '\' as part of the Id, so you would have to get rid of the '\n' from your string to make it work.
2. In the statement: var documentlink = database + "/doc/" + longId;
   I'm not sure what "database" resolves to but it should resolve to something like "dbs/your_db_id/colls/your_coll_id" You are missing 's' from "/doc/" so this needs to be changed to "/docs/".
   In order to avoid all these issues for creating the documentLink, C# SDK has a UriFactory static class that you can use as follows to get the documentLink(in Uri format) that you can pass onto DeleteDocumentAsync method. Here is how it looks like:
   Uri documentUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(database, collection, longId);

where database is the id of the database and collection is the id of your document collection.

Hope that helps!

Regards,
Rajesh

Comment: thanks for the help, I couldn't remove the \n in the string but I have solved this problem by getting the selflink of the document. However, this can be pretty useful if you can suggest me how I can remove \n.